# HTML / CSS: how to style a Div such that it matches the styling/behavior of Bootstrap buttons

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage that uses Bootstrap's button `class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary"`.

On the same page, I render a `Div` with JavaScript that's clickable.  I assign it an `orders-data` class:

...

```
element.classList.add('orders-data');
```

I would like to get the `Div` to match the styling of the buttons using some CSS.  This is what I have so far:

**CSS**

```
.orders-data {
    border: 1px solid #007bff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.orders-data:hover {
    background-color: #007bff;
    border: 1px solid #007bff;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
```

This seems to work.  But, is there a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you can just add `btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary` classes and adjust styling. Also, what is the purpose to add an element styled as a button and act as button, why don't you want to use the button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this style to make Div element similar to Bootstrap Button.

```
.orders-data {
  cursor:pointer;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #007bff;
  border-color: #007bff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
  user-select: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.orders-data:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0069d9;
  border-color: #0062cc;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this styling to the div:

```css
.orders-data {
    display: block;
    width: 115px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: #0d6efd;
    border-color: #0d6efd;
    
}

.orders-data:hover {
    background-color: #007bff;
    border: 1px solid #007bff;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="orders-data"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

because of : `element.classList.add('orders-data');` you use,
You can add the bootstrap classes to your element going through a loop, so need to write them again.

exemple to demonstrate the idea :

```js
let el = document.querySelector('a');
const classS = ['btn', 'btn-sm', 'btn-outline-primary'];
for (i = 0; i < classS.length; i++) {
  el.classList.add(classS[i])
}
```

```css
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">hello</button>
<a class="shadow" href="#">the world</a>
```

(if your element has no other class, then setAttribute at once will do):

```js
let el = document.querySelector('a');
el.setAttribute('class','btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary' ) ;
```

```css
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">hello</button>
<a class="shadow" href="#">the world</a>
<p><code>setAttribute()</code> removes any value already there , shadow class is not there anymore!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome here bro,
this is work without any problems but you can take more fast way than this
you can just add the button classes for div this classes global in bootstrap you can use it in any element you want like

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary"> button</button>
<div class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">
  button
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like the button you want:

```css
.orders-data {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.orders-data:active{
  outline:5px auto rgb(14,98,201) ;
}
```

```html
<div class='orders-data'>
  Bootstrap Button
</div>
```